# How to add scrollview to the grid in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Adding a scroll view to the following grid works but the rectangle at bottom is not visible fully,I want to add scroll view to the content panel grid so that I can view all the rectangles even if its more than 10

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,-45">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ScrollViewer >
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF283742" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="184" Margin="10,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF876D6D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="130" Margin="10,192,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF565D41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="133" Margin="237,189,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF322929" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="10,327,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF2F5151" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="98" Margin="10,537,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF1E7870" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="108" Margin="237,537,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Grid With StackPanel and Position your rectangles,

```
  <ScrollViewer Height="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF283742" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="184" Margin="10,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF876D6D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="130" Margin="10,192,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF565D41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="133" Margin="237,189,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF322929" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="10,327,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF2F5151" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="98" Margin="10,537,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF1E7870" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="108" Margin="237,537,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>    
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly set the height of the Grid in the Scrollviewer or change the Grid for a Stackpanel and adjust the rectangles.